# how to compute Hilbert class field of $\Bbb Q(\zeta_{23})$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

I want to construct the Hilbert class field of $K=\Bbb Q(\zeta_{23}).$ I have no clue how to construct it except that I know that $[H(K):K]=3$ from Sage. Any references or comments are appreciated.

Comment: Maybe find a cubic extension ramified only over 23? Then if you adjoin that to your Cyclotomic extension you will get something unramifed over 23 and hence unramified everywhere

Comment: The claim in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_class_field is that you have to add a root of $x^3-x-1$ ; I didn't verify it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The cyclotomic field $K=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{23})$ contains the quadratic field $F=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-23})$, and $F$ has class number $3$ (it is the first quadratic field, when those are ordered by absolute value of the discriminant, that has class number divisible by $3$). Thus, $F$ has an unramified cubic extensions $H$, and since the degree of $K$ is coprime with $3$, the extensions $H$ and $K$ are disjoint, so that the compositum $HK$ is an unramified cubic extension of $K$. Thus, your problem is reduced to finding the Hilbert class field of $F$. Magma (and presumably also Sage?) will just give it to you. It is the splitting field over $\mathbb{Q}$ of the cubic polynomial $x^3-x+1$.

In summary, the Hilbert class field of $K$ is obtained by adjoining to $K$ a root of $x^3-x+1$.

Comment: small typo: "reduced to finding the Hilbert class field of F" instead of "reduced to finding the Hilbert class field of K" (but edit has to be at least 6 characters)

Comment: Thanks, @Arno, corrected. Hope you are well!

Comment: Thank you, @Alex, for this nice answer. Best wishes for the New Year!